# Can you Iterate through member variables using a for loop, if a vector is of a class

Tags: c++

```
for (std::string& request : recData.getReqest()) //recData is a vector 
    {
    }
```

recData is a vector which stores objects of an X type, X class has a member variable which is "std::string request;" and as I iterate through the for loop I want all objects within recData to have their request member variable processed. Is this possible?

Comment: if `recData` is a `vector` then `recData.getReqest()` won't work since `vector` has no member named `getReqest()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's certainly possible, by changing the `for` loop and using one extra statement:

```
for (auto &r: recData)
{
    std::string &request = r.request;

    // Here's your request, for your loop.
}
```